# 4-Stat CSS Javascript Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

I'm trying to get working code for my button. It'll be used to connect/disconnect. I have 4 buttons already designed.

Basic Connect Button: Button which'll be shown when the page opens.

Connect Button Hover Effect: Another button, will be activated when the mouse hovers over it. Its almost the same just the text is bolder & the color is more dark.

Connected button (Active):  When clicked it should remain on this state,  like when we click on connect button it should be changed to connected & remain active.

Now if we hover over it on connected state it should show disconnect button as hover at that time & then back to normal if clicked again which means it was disconnected.

My code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>

<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.button').click(function() {

    $(this).toggleClass('button1').toggleClass('active');

});   
});




</script>   

<style type="text/css">

a.button {
    background-image:url(img/button_light.png);
    width: 123px;
    height: 43px;
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;

}

a.button:hover {
        background-image:url(img/butto_mouseover.png);
    width: 123px;
    height: 43px;
}

a.button:active { 
        background-image:url(img/button_clicked.png);
    width: 123px;
    height: 43px;
}


a.button1:hover { 
    background-image:url(img/button_disconnect.png);
    width: 123px;
    height: 43px;
}

</style>



</head>
<body>
<a class="button" href="#" ></a>

</body>
</html>
```

Can any body help me in this.

Comment: So what is the problem?  How is this not working? Are there errors reported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:active` is a [psuedo class selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act) that is applied automatically when the user is holding down the mouse button on the element and removed when you let go. You would need to change `a.button:active` to `a.button.active` for your javascript to work.